# How to read user's advanced text sizing options programmatically?

Tags: .net, vb.net, text-size

On Windows 10, under Advanced Display Settings, the user gets the option"advancing sizing of text and other items" where they can independently scale certain items, such as title bars and menu bars, up or down. As far as I know this wasn't possible in Windows 7?

I've got a VB.Net app where I need to be able to detect the user's selections. I'm already reading and adapting to the user's overall DPI settings, but I need to take these specific settings into account- and I don't know where to find them. (I appreciate that in an ideal world I wouldn't need to read them, but unfortunately this is one of those odd cases where it's necessary.)

Is there a way I can read these values as variables within my VB.Net app?

Comment: This has always been possible, it has nothing to do with DPI.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks, but regardless of whether it was possible in previous Windows or not, the question - how can I read the user's chosen setting for each within VB.Net? - still stands.